# Why is my Set-DisplayResolution command in Powershell missing?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm using Parallels on my Mac to run the Windows 8.1 operating system. Parallels has a quirk that resets the screen resolution to the highest level every time it is restarted. Thus, I'd like to write a short Powershell script that will automatically sets my screen resolution to the one I prefer. The problem is, using either the `Set-ScreenResolution` or the `Set-DisplayResolution` gives me the following error:

> Set-DisplayResolution : The term 'Set-DisplayResolution' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script  file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct  and try again. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Set-DisplayResolution
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-DisplayResolution:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Any idea why this is happening?

I'm using Windows 8.1 64 bit. The version of my Powershell is 4.0. I'm using Parallels 9 as my virtual machine on the Yosemite operating system (mac).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Get-DisplayResolution` and `Set-DisplayResolution` are only available on Server Core.

Web search points to this [article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/07/07/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-change-my-desktop-monitor-resolution-via-windows-powershell.aspx) showing how to call the appropriate user32 functions from PowerShell.  It can hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: and finally available in the powershell gallery https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/2a631d72-206d-4036-a3f2-2e150f297515/

Comment: @Bernhard, the link is dead, but the PowerShell Gallery now offers a community-contributed module with such commands, [`DisplaySettings`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/DisplaySettings)  ([repo](https://github.com/lust4life/display-resolution)).